# Underage adsense account

Tags: google-adsense

I'm still 14, can I use my name as the payee? I do have a bank account using my name.
Will adsense not pay me if it finds out about my age?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it looks like the *AdSense account* needs to be in the name of someone over 18. (Presumably for privacy, liability, etc.) I'd assume they have no real way of seeing who owns the bank account eventually receiving funds. That said, you should set aside some time to read the [terms of use](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms)

From section 1:

> By enrolling in the Program, You represent that You are at least 18 years of age

and section 4:

> Google reserves the right to investigate, at its own discretion, any activity that may violate this Agreement[…]

and section 6:

> Google may investigate any activity that may violate this Agreement. Google may at any time, in its sole discretion, terminate all or part of the Program, terminate this Agreement, or suspend or terminate the participation of any Property in all or part of the Program for any reason.

You get the general idea.

The AdSense product forum seems to be littered with people asking this general question. [Here's one](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/kEczqalwjZQ) who seems to've pulled it off, though it looks like parents got involved, as I suspected.